# Using multiple MySQL joins to each get multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have a table "rate" that has the columns "id", "location", "local_rate", "long_rate".
Id is the integer value to differentiate the clients. The results are grouped by location. Each location group has an entry from each client. Each client has a different local_rate and long_rate. What I need to get is the location, the lowest local_rate and the client with that rate, and the lowest long_rate and the client with that rate. There will be a row for each location in the table. If there are multiple matching results for a rate it should just pick one and return the value and the client id with that value.

Results will be displayed as:

```
location1 | id(min_local_rate) | min_local_rate | id(min_long_rate) | min_long_rate
location2 | id(min_local_rate) | min_local_rate | id(min_long_rate) | min_long_rate
....
```

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT local.location, local.id, local.local_rate, long.id, long.long_rate
FROM
(SELECT MIN(local_rate), location, id FROM rate GROUP BY location) local
JOIN
(SELECT MIN(long_rate), location, id FROM rate GROUP BY location) long
ON local.location = long.location
GROUP BY local.location;
```

What I'm getting back is the same local client id in every row and the same long client id in every row. The location, local rates, and long rates are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can calculate the minimum and maximum local rates for each location in one subquery.  Then, you can join back to the original data to get the client ids.

If there is only one client with the min/max, then the following should do what you want:

```
select l.location, l.minlr, rmin.id, l.maxlr, rmax.id
from (select location, min(local_rate) as minlr, max(local_rate) as maxlr
      from rate r
      group by location
     ) l join
     rate rmin
     on rmin.location = l.location and rmin.local_rate = l.minlr join
     rate rmax
     on rmax.location = l.location and rmax.local_rate = l.maxlr;
```

If there are multiple rows that match, this will produce multiple rows for each location.  You question doesn't specify what to do in this case.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I'm not looking for the max rate at all. I'm looking for the lowest local rate and the lowest long rate.

Comment: @NewGuy . . . I was just using "rates" generically.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to try making the objective a little more clear. The subquery by itself does exactly what I need for location, min_local_rate, and min_long_rate. The full query returns no rows.

Comment: @NewGuy . . . That is what this query does, although the ids come after the rates.

Comment: Not sure if I transcribed it wrong originally, but it's working now. Thank you!